# Xcode 8: Archive build fails (for nested frameworks) with link errors. Regular build compiles successfully

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, swift3

**EDIT**
Seems like the issue has been drilled down to the fact that it builds in debug mode but not in release mode. Still trying to understand why it builds in one and not the other

**ORIGINAL ISSUE**

I have a Xcode workspace with the following structure.

Workspace:

1. UIProject
2. FrameworkA
3. FrameworkB

FrameworkB is nested in FrameworkA so FrameworkA is dependent on FrameworkB. Both are custom frameworks that I have created.

It builds and compiles fine. When I try to archive it, I get the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "ADI4ONS.Connection4ONS.connectionStat.getter : Swift.Bool", referenced from:
      type metadata for AircraftServices.connection in Connection.o
  "ADI4ONS.Connection4ONS.connectionStat.setter : Swift.Bool", referenced from:
      type metadata for AircraftServices.connection in Connection.o
  "ADI4ONS.Connection4ONS.connectionStat.materializeForSet : Swift.Bool", referenced from:
      type metadata for AircraftServices.connection in Connection.o
  "ADI4ONS.Connection4ONS.connectionString.getter : Swift.String", referenced from:
      type metadata for AircraftServices.connection in Connection.o
  "ADI4ONS.Connection4ONS.connectionString.setter : Swift.String", referenced from:
      type metadata for AircraftServices.connection in Connection.o
  "ADI4ONS.Connection4ONS.connectionString.materializeForSet : Swift.String", referenced from:
      type metadata for AircraftServices.connection in Connection.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Where ADI4ONS is frameworkB and AircraftServices is FrameworkA. Any help is welcomed.

**Project/Target Configuration**

1. Bitcode is enabled
2. Build Active Architecture only is set to NO ( tried 'Yes as well )
3. Xcode 8 with swift 3.0

**Experiments Tried**
Some of the things I've tried

1. Tried setting Archive to Debug ( instead of the default Release in edit schema ) : NO LUCK
2. Created a separate workspace for the UIProject and imported the frameworks binary into that . Archives successfully : WORKS GREAT ( but not what I want )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, After a ton of research and experimentation, here's my result.

So I figured out the parameter that was causing issues in Release mode build. It is the “Swift Compiler – Code Generation: Optimization Level”. It has three values

1. None [-Onone]

   - Default value for debug
   - Also works for my release.
2. Fast, Single-File Optimization [-O] 
   -Works in Release

   - Most likely the value I’m going to set
3. Fast , Whole Module Optimization [-O -whole–module-optimization]

   - Default value for release
   - This causes the break

I was trying to research more into the WMO but didn’t dig too deep into it. Seems like it was introduced in Xcode 7 .

Also my frameworks were both in Swift .

Comment: This was (almost) a life saver. In my app, I have a separate set of code arranged as a Framework. I was getting multiple "undeclared type" errors. I suspect they're from using overlapping names between the app & framework. Using option (2) removed 7 errors. Now there is just one left.... hmm...

Comment: Discovered the same thing. Came looking for answers as to why this is the case. Hopefully someone can shed some light!

Comment: Where exactly is this "Release mode build" button?

Comment: It's only visible in the parent .framework -> build settings -> Swift compiler - code generation -> Optimisation level. Trying to get this nested framework thing to work in playground. I get it to work with regular Run. But not in playground. Only multiple frameworks that doesn't call other frameworks. It sort of works, but only for the child framework. The parent becomes unavailable.